# Can I retrieve and access a simple JSON object via HTTP in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: macros, libreoffice-calc, import, api, json

I've located a web API resource that I'd like to access from LibreOffice Calc.

It returns a simple JSON/JavaScript object that's basically just a handful of name value pairs, one of which I want to pull out and put in a cell.

I know programming but have barely ever used spreadsheets. From Googling I still can't tell which programming language I should use for this and whether I would need any external addons or just the functions built in to LibreOffice.

(I'm happy to migrate this question to StackOverflow if it's decided that it really belongs there.)

Comment: LibreCalc should support modern REST APIs and implement a FILTERJSON function ([feature request](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=113974)) similar to the existing FILTERXML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the easiest way is using the GetRest Plugin for LibreOffice.

You can use separate cells, one for pulling the data, one for formatting it, and so on. However by combining functions (or creating a macro), you can achieve quite a bit of formatting in a single cell.

## Example: Getting Current Bitcoin Spot Price

For this, I'll be using the Coinbase API, many of their calls do not require authentication.

> https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-spot-price

1. Download and install the plugin. You will have two new functions:

- `GET()` which accepts the API endpoint as an argument
- `PARSEJSON()` which accepts two arguments:

  1. JSON source. This can be any local or online file as long as it is proper JSON. We'll be using the `GET()` output.
  2. The structure/hierarchy of the JSON file pointing to the specific value you want.

**HTTP Request**

```
GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/:currency_pair/spot
```

For the currency_pair, I want the BTC value in USD, so that will be replaced with `BTC-USD`

**JSON Response**

```json
{
  "data": {
    "amount": "1015.00",
    "currency": "USD"
  }
}
```

### Using Two Cells

In A1:

```
=GET("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot")
```

In A2, parse the JSON response. The parsing works at the object name level, separated by a period. This is passed as an argument into the function in one of two ways, if the JSON contains an array, we specify the name of the array and object index as `arrayName.get(i).objectName`. Our example is just an object with two `"key":"value"` pairs, so the format is `objectName.keyName`:

```
=PARSEJSON(A1, "data.amount")
```

Which reads as:

```
23966.93
```

### Using One Cell

Method is essentially the same, however instead of passing the cell as the first argument, we're passing the entire `GET()` function:

```
=PARSEJSON(GET("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot"), "data.amount")
```

### Formatting

The JSON response passes a string value, which is wrapped in a function, so you cannot any of the options *within that cell* to format it currency or a number.

However I still want to have the "$" in front of it on my spreadsheet, so we can concatenate strings to add this prefix, our resulting functions looks like this:

```
=CONCAT("$",PARSEJSON(GET("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot"), "data.amount"))
```

This fits into once cell, can be updated by pressing F9 (be mindful that every refresh to an open API endpoint is taking some of their server bandwidth, so try to limit the amount of refreshes. If you can re-use a cell without having to create another call, that's even more considerate.)

Comment: On Ubuntu I got an error installing the plugin that I could solve by installing `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-java-common`. Also you need to use semicolons instead of commas e.g. `=PARSEJSON(A1; "data.amount")`. Thanks for the detailed explanations, I was finally able to get this to work. Currently the plugin can be downloaded [here](https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/4ed97370af8355feabf50cb2909198a0).

Comment: I have one problem though, that I just can't solve. I get the BTC price in Euro with `=PARSEJSON(GET("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-EUR/spot"); "data.amount")` which works fine, but when want to calculate with that value `=A59*2` it says "Error: Wrong data type", For `=VALUE(A59)*2` it says "Error: Invalid Argument".

Comment: It seems to be something with the locale, when I substitute dot for comma in the value it works `=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE( PARSEJSON(GET("http://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?access_key=5904fda861078a50b5634efc6590d8c4"); "rates.AUD"); "." ;","))`. Maybe it's the same with semicolon or comma in the syntax.

Answer (score 5):

After 4 years, they still haven't implemented the suggested `FILTERJSON()`.

This is obviously not a real solution, but one that works for now, for very simple cases:

1. Send a request to your API using: `=WEBSERVICE("http://example.com/v1/stuff")` in eg. cell A1
2. In cell A2 for example, add `=MID(A1;SEARCH("rootProperty";A1)+2;10)` (remember to change the separator characters (semicolons in my case) to match your locale in LibreOffice)

Explanation:

- `MID()` will take a partial text from the full response
- `SEARCH()` will look for the beginning index of the given text, eg. "rootProperty"
- `+2` is the offset where to start reading the value (basically substring)
- `10` is how many characters to read from the beginning of the text `SEARCH()` found (after the `+2` offset)

So if for example you get the following response in cell A1:

```
{
  "id": 12345678,
  "something": "Example",
  "myThing": "Hello",
  "another": "Not needed"
}
```

And your cell A2 has the formula: `=MID(A1;SEARCH("myThing";A1);13)`

What the cell would have as value is: `myThing": "He`
Which is `13` characters starting from the first character in `myThing`, that you searched for in `SEARCH()`.

So obviously you wouldn't want to have the `myThing": "` part of it. To only get the value `Hello` from `myThing`, you would use this formula: `=MID(A1;SEARCH("myThing";A1)+11;5)`.

This will:

1. Find where `myThing` begins (caveat: if there's two instances of the string, you'll get the first one)
2. Return 5 characters from the offset. So: `myThi`
3. Then offsets the beginning to be from index `11` (the `+11` in the formula)
4. So it skips the first 11 characters (`myThing": "`) and returns 5 characters from there on, which is `Hello`

Of course, it's still fairly manual, but at least one workable way for simple things. Good luck!

Comment: After 8 years till no `FILTERJSON`!

Answer (score 1):

Probably better to ask on StackOverflow, but yes, you can retrieve and access/convert a JSON object with Python, which works very well with LibreOffice Calc.  You can work the problem in both directions, by either using Python to control LibreOffice, or have LibreOffice run Python scripts, depending upon your needs.

As for converting JSON to something LibreOffice can use (csv), there's a good beginner explanation at [Applied Informatics](http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-parse-and-convert-json-to-csv-using-python/).

Answer (score 1):

They did open the issue [in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534203/does-libreoffice-calc-support-json-file-importing-sorting/36210005#36210005). 
There are a couple of other ideas:

- try to install [this plugin](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/libreoffice-getrest-plugin-1) -- that one doesn't seem to work - for me it didn't
- use an [online parser](http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm) to create CSV

Comment: So I first need to grab the object as CSV and put that into one sheet which I would access from my main sheet somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing the answer of @sentientflesh:

The GetRest plugin is available for download here:
https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/4ed97370af8355feabf50cb2909198a0#file-libreofficegetrestplugin-oxt

It still works with LibreOffice Calc v.7.1 using the get and parsejson functions as documented here:
https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/libreoffice-getrest-plugin-1